# Page jump to a different section in the Page Viewer Web Part?

Tags: web-part, page-viewer-web-part

I need to jump to a different section of the page viewer when clicking on a link.

i.e "back to top" or "back to bottom"

Using href="#divID"  works outside of sharepoint... but not inside it.

Any help will be appreciated.

p.s. I have no access to the master page.

Comment: It seems like it doesn't work for only IE, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is useful for you, you may try something like this using jQuery:

```
$('#s4-workspace').animate({ scrollTop: $("#divID").offset().top - 80 }, 0);
```

Comment: Hmm I'll give it a shot, previously. not sure why though but .animate and scroll functions do not seem like they want to work in Internet Explorer.